# Drupal module to retrieve external website content and populate form for a user to review

Tags: forms, drupal-7, information-retrieval, data-retrieval, mediametadataretriever

First question here so hi Guys.
I've spent ages looking for a module to retrieve data from any website and add the content to a form. I was convinced allot of people whould have used something similar but cannot find anything.

Basically we have a Drupal 7 site that amongst other things allows users to submit data about there website/company. Before they complete the form by hand i wanted them to be able to simply type in their URL then click a button named "retrieve info" and fetch and scrape the data from their site either from meta tags or html tags (should be configurable) and insert the data in a form before they save or preview the information.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module with something like the [Feeds XPath Parser](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser) or [Feeds extensible parsers](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ex) to scrape external site HTML.

I'm fairly certain you can attach feeds to nodes, but you may have to experiment with giving users access to creating that node type, and initializing the feed. Otherwise, you could look into running a custom cron job or rule to trigger the feed based on the field value in the node or form.